# jQuery UI Dialog Caches for quick second

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have multiple images on a page, that pops up the related  big image in a dialog box.

But when I click image 2, images 1 shows first before image 2 comes in, in the first .5 seconds.
How can I clear image 1 out completed when I close it?

I try destroy, but that kills the entire functionality when time to click image 2.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: 'middle',
        draggable: false,
        minWidth: '960',
        maxheight:'500',
        overlay: true,
        modal: true,
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        position:'top',
        close: function(event, ui) {
      $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

.dialog('destroy') only removes the dialog capabilities from that div.  you need to empty it!

```
close: function(event, ui) {
  $("#dialog").empty().dialog("destroy");
}
```

edit: ahh, right, you want to keep the dialog, but empty it right?   take off the .dialog('destory')  then, just empty it.

```
close: function(event, ui) {
  $("#dialog").empty();
}
```

Comment: ah beat you to it i think, i did tried that before u made the edit lol,
anyhow the dialog pops up , but the content inside its not coming in...

atleast im getting closer..ha

Comment: hm,  can you post the code that you are calling the dialog up with?

Comment: cool, if my answered helped you get it working, feel free to click that checkmark beside it :)

Answer (score 0):

I use remove instead of empty..

```
close: function(event, ui) {
  $("#dialog").remove().dialog("destroy");
}
```